# Use compact lists when converting from docx to markdown

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I'm using pandoc on Windows to convert from a `.docx` file to a `.md` file.

The flags I'm using are the following:

```
pandoc --wrap none --to markdown_github --output fms.md "FMS.docx"
```

When I view the output markdown file, it has newlines separating each list item. The documentation defines this as a [*loose list*](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#bullet-lists) such as the one below.

```
- one

- two

- three
```

I want to use a *compact list* for the output such as the one below.

```
- one
- two
- three
```

Is there a flag to make pandoc output a compact list?

If not, how can I use a filter to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no flag to achieve this, but there is a simple solution using pandoc's *filter* functionallity. Internally, list items are represented as a list of blocks; a list is compact if all block items only consist of `Plain` blocks.  If all items consist of only a single paragraph, then it is sufficient to change the type of the item block from `Para` (for *paragraph*) to `Plain`.

The Lua program below does just that.  Save it and use it as a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html): `pandoc -t markdown --lua-filter the-filter.lua your-document.docx` (requires pandoc 2.1 or later):

```lua
local List = require 'pandoc.List'

function compactifyItem (blocks)
  return (#blocks == 1 and blocks[1].t == 'Para')
    and {pandoc.Plain(blocks[1].content)}
    or blocks
end

function compactifyList (l)
  l.content = List.map(l.content, compactifyItem)
  return l
end

return {{
    BulletList = compactifyList,
    OrderedList = compactifyList
}}
```

If one prefers Haskell over Lua, it's also possible to use the filter below  with `pandoc -t markdown --filter the-filter.hs your-document.docx`:

```hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter compactifyList

compactifyList :: Block -> Block
compactifyList blk = case blk of
  (BulletList items)         -> BulletList $ map compactifyItem items
  (OrderedList attrbs items) -> OrderedList attrbs $ map compactifyItem items
  _                          -> blk

compactifyItem :: [Block] -> [Block]
compactifyItem [Para bs] = [Plain bs]
compactifyItem item      = item
```

The same would also be possible using a Python filter in case neither Lua nor Haskell is an option.  See pandoc's [filters](http://pandoc.org/filters.html) page for details.

Comment: Does anyone have an example Python script that can be used as a filter for this to share?